# For some reason the dropdown only works when loged in as Wp-Admin

Tags: wordpress, dropdown, navbar

As the title says, i have a navbar with a dropdown menu - that works perfect when logged in as wp-admin. But when i enter the site as a normal guest, the dropdown doesnt work.

How is this possible? Anyone have any knowledge in the matter?

Quick help would be awesome.

Link to site -> https://venturelegal.se/

Comment: It looks like some of your JS code is only loaded for logged in admins

Comment: Hm yea, that might be it. Clearly its working as Wp-admin, with all links correct. While entering the site it doesnt drop down at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could add the CSS and JS of Bootstrap like this:

```
function bootstrap_scripts() {
    /* Bootstrap CSS */
    wp_enqueue_style('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '4.1.0');

    /* Bootstrap JS */
    wp_enqueue_script('bootstrap', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '4.1.0',  true);
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'bootstrap_scripts');
```

Make sure, that the path to the JS and CSS file is inside the `/css/` and `/js/` folder of your theme or change the path in the code.

And you could change the Bootstrap version from `4.1.0` to your version

Comment: I uploaded this in my "functions.php" and made sure path was right and version. Still no dropdown menu.

Comment: You have a problem with your CSS code.

The class `.navigation .dropdown .other-dropdown` has an `opacity:0`. So it's not visible.

And the `top: -100%; left: 0;`prevent it from being in the visible area. You need to fix that. And I guess there is some JS code that does that only for admins.